# calculate angle when delta x = 0,001

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm busy with a homework assignment (differentiating), and I don't understand it because the book has no explanation given. In the book it says:

"Show that when your calculator is on the setting RAD(radians) and $\Delta x = 0.001$, that the angle of the slope of $O(0,0)$ to $y=\sin x$ is about 45°"

I don't know how to put my calculator on the RAD setting.

What I tried was $\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sin 0.001}{0.001})$, because $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ is how u calculate the slope, and I thought that when u get the inverse tangent of the slope you get the angle.
I don't get 45° as my answer when I tick it into my calculator.

What am I doing wrong?

Please don't use symbols in your answers, I hardly know any.

Can someone edit my question into LaTeX?

Edit:

How come the arctan of 1 on my calculator doesn't return 45 but 0.7853...

Edit 2:

When I put it back on degrees mode and I take the arctan of 1 it returns 45. My question is solved, but can someone explain why the arctan is different in radians mode?

More importantly can someone explain why I need to put it on radians mode?

Comment: Your calculator is probably set to degrees mode by default, and as a result, trigonometric functions will give different results than when your calculator is set to radians. You should Google your calculator model to find an instruction manual that will help you set it to radian mode.

Comment: I don't know how to use your calculator either. I would advise you to consult the manual for definitive answers. If your calculator defaults to "degree mode", I would suggest that you dispose of it in an environmentally responsible manner and replace it with a more usable one.

Comment: Yes, thanks I figured out how to put it in radians mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compute $\frac{\sin 0.001}{0.001}$ on your calculator, you should get $\approx 1$. $\arctan$ of that is $45$ degrees or $\frac{\pi}{4}$ in radians.

Comment: When I take the sin of 0.001 and divide it by 0.001 I get 0.01745....

Comment: When I take the inverse tangent of that I end up with a number very close to 1. I'm confused

Comment: Are you using $\arctan$ in radian mode?

Comment: just normal numbers, I dont know how to set my calculator on radians

Comment: There will be a "Degrees, Radians, Grads" setting that is how you can change the scales.

Comment: @JbKing I just noticed, thanks

Comment: with radians mode I indeed get around 1 out of sin(0.001)/0.001 but the arctan of that is not 45?

Comment: When I put it back on degrees mode and I take the arctan of 1 it returns 45. My question is solved, but can someone explain why the arctan is different in radians mode?

Comment: Because degrees and radians are different measures. Please refer to your textbook for an explanation.